# Can't rename project TortoiseSVN & Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Trying to rename a project under the control of TortiseSVN/Subversion.

Running svn on the server where SVN is installed.

```
svn rename svn://192.168.0.1/MyProject svn://192.168.0.1/Installer
```

Gives

```
svn: No repository found in 'svn://192.168.0.1'
```

yet

```
svn ls svn://192.168.0.1/MyProject
```

Lists the file/directories in the project as expected.

What might I be doing wrong?

Thanks..

UPDATE:

My aim in doing this was to rename projects in a consistent manner. After moving the project and checking out it seems to work however after the renaming the Solution, Project, Folders & Files in Visual Studio/Windows Explorer I was no longer able to commit. 3 of the folders showed a red exclamation Mark even after telling TSVN which files to add and delete.  I have rolled back to the backup I took before I started this task.  I might try this again someday....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like MyProject is the root of your svn wc. Just rename the directory the normal way for your OS and it should just work.

Comment: Isn't MyProject the root of the repository rather than the WC?

Comment: Subversion is using E:\DEV\SVN\Repository as the repository for this and other projects. MyProject is E:\DEV\SVN\Repository\MyProject